# Bitbucket Pipelines SSH credentials do not work

Tags: bitbucket-pipelines

I followed this instruction

https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/use-ssh-keys-in-bitbucket-
pipelines-847452940.html

and I made:

1. I created SSH key using in Settings -> Pipelines - SSH Keys.
2. I copied this public key to ~/.ssh/authorized_keys on the remote host.
3. I added the IP of my server toKnown hosts.

I have such bitbucket-pipelines.yml:

```
image: php:7.1.1

pipelines:   custom: # Pipelines that are triggered manually
    deployment-to-prod:
      - step:
          script:
            - apt-get update && apt-get install -y unzip
            - apt-get -y install openssh-server
            - ssh webmaster@XXX.XXX.XX.XX sh /home/webmaster/scripts/update_live.sh
```

When I run this pipeline I have:

*apt-get update && apt-get install -y unzip15s
apt-get -y install openssh-server2m 43s
ssh webmaster@XXX.XXX.XX.XX sh /home/webmaster/scripts/update_live.sh<1s
+ ssh webmaster@XXX.XXX.XX.XX sh /home/webmaster/scripts/update_live.sh 
**Permission denied, please try again.
Permission denied, please try again.
Permission denied (public key, password)**.*

My questions:

1. Why my Docker machine cannot establish SSH connection (Permission
   denied)?
2. Do I really have to install openssh-server? Without it
       'ssh' command cannot be recognized (No such file or directory).

Comment: Have you got any solution? if yes, can you please post it here?

Answer (score 1):

One of the most common issues about this is that you may not have set the correct permissions for the authorized_keys file.

```
chmod 600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Also, make sure the .ssh folder also has its proper rights.

```
chmod 700 ~/.ssh
```